# Updating parent version of a non-child aggregate module

Tags: maven

In my project I have an aggregate module that I don't want to build along with the rest of the project. The module is only meant for testing some of the children to the parent.

The project structure is basically like this:

```
↓ : child (defined as a <module> in the parent)
↑ : parent (defined with the <parent> tag)

       parent
        ↑  ↑
     __/    \__
    /          ↓
aggregate    children
  ↑
  ↓
child
```

The build process is more or less like this (jenkins pipeline):

1. `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=xyz` for parent/project
2. build project
3. `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=xyz` for aggregate
4. build aggregate

The problem is that when I try to set the version of the aggregate module (step 3), maven outputs an error that it cannot resolve the aggregates parent.

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for aggregateModule:dev-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact parentModule:dev-SNAPSHOT
```

**How can I update the parent of the aggregate module so that it finds the newly built local parent artifact?**

What I have tried so far is

- versions:update-parent for aggregate

  - Made no difference.
- processAllModules flag for versions:set for parent

  - Made no difference (not sure if I actually expected it to...).
- using LATEST as parent version in aggregate

  - Worked to some extent, but seems to be deprecated.

Comment: You can create a maven profile for custom build.

Comment: I know that it is possible to do it with profiles, it's just that there is no reason that this shouldn't work...but yea, I'm probably going to go for using a profile instead.

Answer (score 0):

The goal `versions:update-parent` usually ignores SNAPSHOT versions. So try

```
versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true
```

Comment: The first step of the build process is to set the versions of the parent/project to something that is not a SNAPSHOT version, so unfortunately the `allowSnapshots` option does not help.

Comment: Ok, then you need to be more specific. If there is a higher version of the parent POM in your local repository (than the one specified in your POM), then `versions:update-parent` should replace the old one with the new one.

Comment: So I set the version for the parent using `versions:set -DnewVersion=xyz` and execute `mvn install`. Should there not be an artifact of the parent with the version `xyz` in the local repository now?

So then when I update the parent version with `versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=xyz` it should match with the newly built parent...or am I completely off the mark here?